# Edit database column parameters from laravel (tinker)

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-artisan

So I have database with table, where I need to edit one column, make it nullable, to be specific. How can I access it from php artisan tinker, or maybe somehow re-run migration on one table without losing data from it?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations
you can see it on this site Column Modifiers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With tinker you cannot modify schema table. You need to create a migration like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AlterTableUsers extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
            $table->string('name', 50)->nullable()->default(null)->change();
        });
    }

}
```

In this case, we make name nullable with default value null.

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#modifying-columns

Comment: thanks a lot, could not find it in docs by myself for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You can just run the suggested code:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->nullable()->default(null)->change();
});
```

directly from tinker

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-run migration or add new migration that alters the existing table depends on whether  you are coding on **production** mode or **development** mode. Generally on development mode re-running migration may be best option(due to dummy data)..On other hand; on production mode, if the data is important ..we generally add the new migration that updates the existing table (because data may be important to us..)